# Using .net control in Sql query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

The problem that i am having is that im trying to query my database based off the currently logged in user. The value for the user is stored as the appid.text and the object "Here" but no matter what i do i cant get the query to pull up the information for the specific user. If i remove the "Where" clause everything works but its pulls the data for all the users instead of just the one user. Any help is welcome.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string here = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
    appid.Text = here;

    string connectionString =
        System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

    // Create SQLDataSource.
    SqlDataSource sqlDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
    sqlDataSource.ID = "SqlDataSource123";
    this.Page.Controls.Add(sqlDataSource);
    // Bind ConnectionString to SQLDataSource.
    sqlDataSource.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    string query = "SELECT Nkey, AppID, Skey, ckey, quad, expyr FROM [dbo].[wallets]  WHERE appid = '" + Here + "' ";
    sqlDataSource.SelectCommand = query;
    // Bind SQLDataSource to GridView after retrieving the records.
    GridView1.DataSource = sqlDataSource;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: That is no C code. I assume it is C#, but not sure, yo please add the correct tag yourself.

Comment: What is the value of the Here variable?

Comment: If `Here` is a control, you have to get the text out of it, probably by using `Here.Text`.

Comment: debug and check the value of here in your code and then compare it with appid from database for that specific user

Comment: Really the column name for user is AppID?

Comment: I have 2 objects that pull the same data (here and appid.text) and both are unable to complete the request. When debugging i get no errors as if the code functioned as it should and that there were no matching results. I linked the appid to a textbox as a test to see if the data was being pulled in as it is. Its just not working withing the query it self.

Comment: Rally when you get all records see same value in appid.Text and in the column AppID.   Run the query in SSMS.

Comment: This is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection. Please do not build SQL queries by string concatenation; use parameterized queries.

Comment: @DanielMann Just how is Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey going to introduce an injection attack?

Comment: @Blam I said *potentially*. If he's writing one query like that, chances are good he's writing other queries like that. I don't think anyone can make the argument that it's a good practice to build SQL queries via string concatenation.

Comment: @Daniel Mann what im trying to do is create a method from which when the user is logged and the page loads the the sqldatasource query runs and pulls a data from a take in the database where the value equals = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();

Comment: @user3266908 I didn't ask what you were doing -- I was trying to educate you about a very, very bad practice that is one of the leading causes of security breaches. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Comment: @Daniel Mann I meant no disrespect. i was just informing you of what i was attempting to do.  new to programming...

Comment: @user3266908 - add a `<label>` control named `queryText` to your form, then right before `GridView1.DataSource = sqlDataSource;` put the line `queryText.Text = query;`. That will show you the query you're sending to SQL Server. If that doesn't give you the answer please edit your question and add the value of the `query` variable, then add a comment that you've done so -- the comment will alert folks in the comment stream that there's more information about your question.

Comment: There where clause is using captial "H", instead of "h" for HERE

Comment: @Ed Gibbs - i got the following 'SELECT ckey FROM [dbo].[wallets] WHERE appid = 'f67a8134-9ffc-4be3-b0cb-207ae02be3c3' ' which tells me that the  " '' "  are making it into the query it self but i have tried a few things but i was unable to make it work or remove the ''. Any ideas ?

Comment: That looks like a valid query. You don't say which type `appid` is, but if it's a `varchar` that's big enough or a `uniqueidentifier` I don't see a problem. Also consider @FembotDBA's advice and get the query working in SSMS first. If you're still having trouble I'd suggest deleting this question and creating a new one with the following: (1) the code like you have above, but fix `Here` vs `here` in the `query` variable, (2) table structure, (3) sample rows including the one you expect to get back, (4) the value of `query`.

Answer (score 1):

First thoughts, looking at your code, the AppId you're sending to SQL is a string and, without seeing your table schema, perhaps the column is defined as an Integer? If it is defined as an integer, then you don't need surrounding single quotes for the query, fyi.

Also, you are using lowercase "here" and then upper case "Here", not sure that would be ok in many programming languages.

If I were having the same issue, I would first get my query working in SSMS. Next, I would, either through breakpoints or a message box, grab the query that it's sending to SQL (copy paste it into SSMS) and execute that in SSMS to check it's returning the data you want.

Most likely your query isn't correct or it isn't being created correctly through your code, data types aren't matching, etc.